# Drag and drop multiple text fields in to multiple positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm using interact.js - See below code. How could I drag and position multiple text fields in to multiple positions? At the moment all text fields uses the same start position `var x = 0, y = 0;`. As a result the text fields snaps to where the final text field was dragged to. So I'm unable to drag each text field in to a different position.

Also is it possible to limit the dragging within its parent DIV. In my case dragging should be allowed only within `OuterWrapper`

```
<button type="button" id="tfButton">Add a Thought</button>
<div id="InputsWrapper"></div>
<div id="OuterWrapper" style="width:500px; height:500px; background-color: #ff6; margin-left:200px;"></div>

<script>
var itmCount = 0;
$(function() {
    function createFields(e) {
        itmCount++;
        var inWrap = $('<div />', { class: 'name-wrapper', id: 'inWrap_'+itmCount }),
            nameWrap = $('<div />', { class: 'name' }).appendTo(inWrap),
            outWrap = $('<div />');

        nameWrap.append(
            $('<input />', { class: 'fTypex', placeholder: 'Thought of the day...', type: 'textarea', id: 'nameWrap_'+itmCount })
        );

        outWrap.append(
            $('<input />', { type: 'textarea', class: 'tfz', id: 'outWrap_'+itmCount})
        );

        $('#InputsWrapper').append(inWrap);
        $('#OuterWrapper').append(outWrap);
    }
    $(document)
        .on('click', '#tfButton', createFields)
})


var x = 0, y = 0;
interact('.tfz')
    .draggable({
        onmove: function (event) {
            x += event.dx;
            y += event.dy;

            event.target.style.webkitTransform =
            event.target.style.transform =
                'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
        }
    })
    .inertia(true)
    .restrict({
        drag: "parent",
        endOnly: true
    });
</script>
```